# Which selector to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to access the input or the class of the input tag through js, as a selector so that I can access the next input element through the keyboard arrows.  By mentioning the class name it is not accessible but after removing all the tags other than input tags and putting just the 'input' as a selector this code works, like in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dMJvv/1/)

But when I try to access it with the class name its not accessible.

Here's my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ryv2/)

Code used:

```
<table id="foo">
<tr>
    <td height="30px">
        <input type="text" class="nav_class" value="">
    </td>
    <td height="30px">
        <input type="text" class="nav_class" value="">
    </td>
    <td height="30px">
        <input type="text" class="nav_class" value="">
    </td>
    <td height="30px">
        <input type="text" class="nav_class" value="">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
$(".nav_class").keydown(function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        alert('a');
        $(this).next(".nav_class").focus();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I suspect this is because `next` retrieves the next sibling, not the next selector.

Answer (score 2):

That is because inputs are wrapped in td. You need to use:

```
 $(this).parent().next().find(".nav_class").focus();
```

**Complete Code:**

```
$(".nav_class").keydown(function (e) {

if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    alert('a');
    $(this).parent().next().find(".nav_class").focus();
}});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ryv2/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `find`  to find the particular find the element

```
 $(".nav_class").keydown(function (e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        $(this).parent().next().find(".nav_class").focus();
    }
});
```

- `$(this).parent()` select current parent
- `$(this).parent().next()` select current parent next siblings
- `$(this).parent().next().find(".nav_class")` find the nav_class

### [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ryv2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
$(".nav_class").keydown(function (e) {    
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        alert('a');
        $(this).closest('td').next().find('.nav_class').focus();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ryv2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo').on('keydown', 'td', function(e) { //use bubbling for less events attaching
    var $next = null, //for caching next td element
        keyCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode // charCode for IE browsers;
    if (keyCode == 40 && ($next = $(this).next()).length) { //save next td elements to do less operations
        $next.find('.nav_class').focus();
    }
});
```